# Некорректно работает обновление Update таблицы GridView, в режиме редактирования при нажатии кнопки Обновить

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Решаю простую задачу на asp net (web app!!!). Столкнулся с очень непонятной для меня проблемой, при редактировании элемента в гридвью. 
Когда перехожу в режим редактировать, у меня есть поле -выпадающий список 
Пример
[image: 1]

Далее выбираю правка
[image: 2]

Меняю текстовые поля и отдел выпадающем списке. Далее в методе GridView1_RowUpdating,

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs 

e) 
{ 
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]; 
TextBox Last_Name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("tb_Last_Name"); 
TextBox First_Name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("tb_First_Name"); 
TextBox Second_Name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("tb_Second_Name"); 
Label lbl_ID_Empl = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_ID_Employee"); 
Label lbl_ID_Dep = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_ID_Department"); 


DropDownList ddl_Department = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1"); 

string commandTextUpdEmpl = String.Format(@"UPDATE [Employee] SET ID_Department = {0} , 
First_Name = '{1}', Second_Name = '{2}', 
Last_Name = '{3}' 
WHERE[ID_Employee] = {4}", ddl_Department.SelectedValue, First_Name.Text, Second_Name.Text, Last_Name.Text, lbl_ID_Empl.Text); 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandTextUpdEmpl, conn); 
conn.Open(); 
//SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [Employee] SET [Last_Name] = @Last_Name, 
// First_Name = @First_Name, /*comment*/ Second_Name = @Second_Name, 
// ID_Department = @ID_Department 
// WHERE[ID_Employee] = @ID_Employee", conn); 

//cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last_Name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Last_Name; 
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@First_Name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = First_Name; 
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@Second_Name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Second_Name; 
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_Department", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_ID_Dep.Text); 
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_Employee", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_ID_Empl.Text); 

Label5.Text = Last_Name.Text + First_Name.Text + Second_Name.Text + ddl_Department.SelectedValue + " " + lbl_ID_Dep.Text + " " + lbl_ID_Empl.Text; 
Label5.Text = cmd.CommandText; 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

GridView1.EditIndex = -1; 
GridView1.DataBind(); 
conn.Close(); 
}
```

специально текст SqlCommand.CommandText вывожу в метку на форме (для проверки).
Получаю:

UPDATE [Employee] 
SET ID_Department = 4 , First_Name = 'Станислав mod', Second_Name = 'Антонович mod', Last_Name = 'Быков mod' WHERE[ID_Employee] = 25

То есть внутри метода он формируется правильно, НО это Update не попадает на обработку SQL server-у (я проверил это через Profiler). В этом и есть основная проблема почему он не передается на сервер из метода.
!!! При update на sql server попадает запрос, который формируется на странице Page1_GridView.aspx в DataSource1, в котором в качестве параметра и берется значение из поля ID_Department, но не из выпадающего списка.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EmployeesConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand=" delete from Employee where ID_Employee = @ID_Employee "
        InsertCommand=" insert into Employee values (@Last_Name, @First_Name, @Second_Name, @ID_Department) "
        SelectCommand="select 
                             d.ID_Department, d.Name,
                             e.Last_Name, e.First_Name,e.Second_Name, e.ID_Employee
                            from Department d
                            left join Employee e on d.ID_Department = e.ID_Department"
        UpdateCommand=" UPDATE [Employee] SET [Last_Name] = @Last_Name, 
                                             First_Name=@First_Name, 
                                             Second_Name=@Second_Name,
                                             ID_Department = @ID_Department
                       WHERE [ID_Employee] = @ID_Employee ">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_Employee" Type="Int16" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Last_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="First_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Second_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_Department" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Last_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="First_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Second_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_Employee" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_Department" Type="Int16" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

То есть проблема ясна, мой основной вопрос в том, почему на обработку попадает UPDATE из SqlDataSource1, а не из метода в коде?
    Как в этом случае поступать, нужно либо как то сделать, чтобы в SqlDataSource1 передавался параметр из выпадающего списка или же сделать так чтобы UPDATE  в SqlDataSource1 не отрабатывал, а отрабатывал update из метода GridView1_RowUpdating. 
    То есть мне как новичку не понятна данная логика работы или же я скорее всего упускаю какие-то нюансы, буду очень благодарен если кто-то подскажет как правильно решить данную проблему.

Comment: Вам наверное в SqlDataSource больше подойдет ControlParameter. Я как то игрался с GridView, может [будет полезно почитать](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2012/01/aspnet-gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел как мне кажется корявое решение данной проблемы - это сделать редирект (Responce.Redirect(Page)) страницы. Но все равно было бы интересно, как можно более красиво и правильно решить данную проблему